# Splunk: How to filter Source and Destination IP Addresses in firewall log

Tags: splunk

Let say I have the following:

Source IP Addresses, `10.1.1.1` & `192.168.1.1`

Destination IP Address `172.16.1.1`

What is the right syntax to search for firewall log for this combination?

Is this the right syntax? I tried it but did not get the result. I've also tried different combination but didn't work too.

> index=firewall src_ip=10.1.1.1 or src_ip=192.168.1.1 and
>   dest_ip=172.16.1.1

Comment: Can't you just try it out?

Comment: @Ruben I already tried it didn't get any result that's why I'm asking here

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You were close.  Use parens like in math and remember boolean operators must be in upper case.  Try this:

```
index=firewall (src_ip=10.1.1.1 OR src_ip=192.168.1.1) AND dest_ip=172.16.1.1
```

Comment: wow ... lower case didn't return anything ... but upper case is working ... many thanks for your help :)